# PHP change quantity in cart array

Tags: php, post, get

I know how to change the quantity in the cart array, however I'm using get the details of the item, and it looks like when the refresh happens it no longer has the id of the item and instead returns these errors.

Is there a way to load the new amount without refreshing?

[image: WAMP Screenshot]

Here is my amount change section:

```
<?php
//section 3
if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && $_POST['item_to_adjust'] != "") {
    // execute some code
    $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $quantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $quantity); // filter everything but numbers
    if ($quantity >= 100) { $quantity = 99; }
    if ($quantity < 1) { $quantity = 1; }
    if ($quantity == "") { $quantity = 1; }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
        $i++;
        while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
            if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_adjust) {
                // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
            } // close if condition
        } // close while loop
    } // close foreach loop
}
?>
```

Here is the get section:

```
<?php
//render cart
$cartOutput = "";
$cartTotal ="";
if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <1){
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align=center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";

}else{
    $i = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item){

        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];

        include_once('config/database.php');
        include_once('object/chair.php');
        $database = new Database();
        $conn = $database->getConnection();
        $chair = new Chair($conn);
        $chair->id = $each_item['details_id'];
        $stmt = $chair->readDetails();    
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $product_name = $row['chair_name']; 
            $price = $row['PRICE'];
        }

        $pricetotal = $price  * $each_item['quantity'];
        $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
        setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_US");
        $pricetotal = number_format($pricetotal, 2, '.', '\'');
        $cartOutput .="<tr>";
        $cartOutput .= "<td>".$product_name."</td>";
        $cartOutput .= "<td>$".$price."</td>";

        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post">
<input name="quantity" type="text" value="'.$each_item['quantity'].'" size="1" maxlength="2" />
        <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" />
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
        </form></td>';

        // $cartOutput .= "<td>".$each_item['quantity']."</td>";
        $cartOutput .= "<td>$".$pricetotal."</td>";
        $cartOutput .= '<td><form action="cart.php" method="post"><input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="X" /><input name="index_to_remove" type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" /></form></td>';
        $cartOutput .="</tr>";
        $i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding after the get comes in alleviates the errors of not having the var defined however it will change the info of items to first entry, and will not work with only one item